# Method not found exception while consuming the Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I am using the following method to generate the script:

```
  /// <summary>
        /// Create single Table script with Data of specified DataBase and Table.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dataBaseName">DataBase Name</param>
        /// <param name="tableName">Table Name</param>
        /// <param name="connectionString">Connection String</param>
        public void CreateScriptTable(string dataBaseName, string tableName, string connectionString)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            ServerConnection serverConnection = new ServerConnection(con);
            Server server = new Server(serverConnection);
            Database database = server.Databases["" + dataBaseName + ""];//Here exception coming
            if (database != null)
            {
                Scripter scripter = new Scripter(server);
                scripter.Options.ScriptData = true;
                scripter.Options.ScriptSchema = true;
                scripter.Options.ScriptDrops = false;
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (Table table in database.Tables)
                {
                    if (table.Name.ToLower() == tableName.ToLower())
                    {
                        sb.Append("DROP TABLE " + table.Name);
                        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                        foreach (string s in scripter.EnumScript(new Urn[] { table.Urn }))
                        {
                            sb.Append(s);
                            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                        string folder = "C:\\temp\\Scripts\\";
                        string filename = folder + tableName + ".sql";
                        System.IO.StreamWriter fs = System.IO.File.CreateText(filename);
                        fs.Write(sb);
                        fs.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**references added:**

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

**Exception:**

```
Method not found: 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.GetDatabaseConnection(System.String)'.

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server.GetExecutionManager()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server.get_ExecutionManager()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.get_DatabaseEngineType()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabaseCollection.get_Item(String name)
   at CreateBatchFile.Form1.CreateScriptTable(String dataBaseName, String tableName, String connectionString) in C:\Test Projects\CreateBatchFile\CreateBatchFile\Form1.cs:line 45
   at CreateBatchFile.Form1.btnGenerateBatchFile_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Test Projects\CreateBatchFile\CreateBatchFile\Form1.cs:line 29
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at CreateBatchFile.Program.Main() in C:\Test Projects\CreateBatchFile\CreateBatchFile\Program.cs:line 19
```

References in Solution Explorer:
[image]

Please let me know where I am moving in wrong direction.

Comment: I'm guessing you are ignoring a nuget downgrade warning or something.

Comment: Thanks for update. just for your reference I added the snapshot of references as well. Please check.